# How to make SSHFS case sensitive

Tags: linux, centos, apache-http-server, sshfs

I am using CentOS 6.4 x86_64 setup as a Apache server (httpd) in VMware Fusion. Through that I am making a SSHFS mount of a directory on my Macbook in the /var/www/html directory so I can do testing on a webpage I am developing.

I recently copied the webpage to a web host and parts of it failed because it could not find the files using the PHP require function. Once I changed the directory names to lowercase (the PHP function looking for the files does an strtolower for the path) everything worked.

On my testing VM, the folders with uppercases in them, for example myDirectory and mydirectory, both worked where on the web server the myDirectory failed.

After doing a bit more testing I created a few directories on my Macbook that were case-sensitive and non-case sensitive. After mounting it with SSHFS, here is my results:

```
[mike@CentOS ~]$ cd tmpDir
[mike@CentOS tmpDir]$ ls
testdirectory1
testDirectory2
[mike@CentOS tmpDir]$ cd testdirectory1
[mike@CentOS testdirectory1]$ cd ..
[mike@CentOS tmpDir]$ cd testDirectory2
[mike@CentOS testDirectory2]$ cd ..
[mike@CentOS tmpDir]$ cd testdirectory2
[mike@CentOS testdirectory2]$ cd ..
```

I believe the problem is with SSHFS being case-insensitive. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not SSHFS but the file system on OS X. HFS is case per default case-insensitve.
HFS remembers the case of a name but the file system is case insensitive.

It is now possible to format an OS X partition with HFS Plus with the "case sensitive" option, but Apple is still prudent and cannot guarantee that applications will not have problems.

Comment: Thanks for the info... that is exactly what I am seeing.